# How to fix error activeMQ port already in use

Tags: activemq-classic

I cannot start activeMQ. it started the day before without problems. It says that the port 1883 is in use. But I cannot find that port 1883 is in use.

I call active mq from the location : C:\Users\"user"\Desktop\apache-activemq-5.15.8 then I use "activemq start"

-redownloading activeMQ
-restarting the PC 3 times
-inserting the .jar files into the corresponding java project

ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ (localhost, ID:DESKTOP-H0C9C4R-2808-1550050121460-0:1)
java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Comment: Did you try to connect with an mqtt client to your 1883 port? It is high probably that your service is already running. If you can't connect the next step would be to find out what process is blocking the port 1883.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and have not yet found a solution. What did you do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind` denotes that the port is already used by any one of the process. You can check this by executing the command in the console -  `netstat -an | find "LISTEN"` (Windows) or `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN"`(Linux & Other OS).

Hope this will help to troubleshoot the issue.